# Suddenly remote desktop tu Ubuntu desktop stopped working

Tags: remote-desktop

For many months I have been using a remote desktop connection from a Windows 11 computer to a remote Ubuntu desktop (22.04), without any problem.

Since this remote Ubuntu desktop doesn't have a physical monitor connected, I installed the package xserver-xorg-video-dummy and I set the /etc/X11/xorg.conf with these contents:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  HorizSync 28.0-80.0
  VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
  # https://arachnoid.com/modelines/
  # 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync
EndSection
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver "dummy"
  VideoRam 256000
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  DefaultDepth 24
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "Card0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Suddenly this stopped working. When I try to connect to the Ubuntu desktop, I am asked the password, I write it and press OK, the remote desktop window is opened for a short instant, and then it disappears. When this happens, the following messages appear in the /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar 18 11:32:29 testcomputer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2736]: [11:32:29:978] [2736:3633] [WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED [0x00090312]
Mar 18 11:32:29 testcomputer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2736]: [11:32:29:981] [2736:3633] [WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED [0x00090313]
Mar 18 11:32:30 testcomputer gnome-remote-de[2736]: Failed to start remote desktop session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Session creation inhibited
Mar 18 11:32:30 testcomputer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2736]: [11:32:29:008] [2736:2736] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_set_error_info:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRINFO_RPC_INITIATED_DISCONNECT [0x0001000          1]
```

Just for reference, when the connection was working, the messages in the syslog where these:

```
Mar 18 11:01:52 testcomputer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2736]: [11:01:52:363] [2736:3435] [WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED [0x00090312]
Mar 18 11:01:52 testcomputer gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2736]: [11:01:52:365] [2736:3435] [WARN][com.winpr.negotiate] - AcceptSecurityContext status SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED [0x00090313]
Mar 18 11:01:52 testcomputer gnome-remote-de[2736]: [RDP.RDPGFX] CapsAdvertise: Accepting capability set with version RDPGFX_CAPVERSION_106, Client cap flags: H264 (AVC444): true, H264 (AVC420): true
Mar 18 11:01:52 testcomputer gnome-remote-de[2736]: [RDP.CLIPRDR] Client capabilities: long format names, stream file clip, file clip no file paths, can lock clip data, huge file support
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Mar 18 11:01:53 testcomputer gnome-shell[2782]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
```

So the point is to understand what does it mean and how to fix this:

```
Mar 18 11:32:30 testcomputer gnome-remote-de[2736]: Failed to start remote desktop session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Session creation inhibited
```

One hint: if I connect briefly a physical monitor to the Ubuntu computer, then I can connect with the remote desktop again. And the funny is that if I disconnect the physical monitor, the remote connection with the "dummy monitor" still works for some minutes, and then suddenly it stops working again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I executed this command:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery -n -t int -s 1
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1768038